# Helix given as integral

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that, the curve
$$\alpha(s)=\left(\frac{a}{c}\int \sin \theta(s)\, ds,\frac{a}{c}\int \cos \theta(s) \, ds,\frac{b}{c}s \right)$$
with $a^2=b^2+c^2$, is a helix and $k/\tau=b/a$

Comment: What's $\theta(s)$?  Is it just any function?  More importantly: what have you tried?

Comment: @JesseMadnick : I have not tried anything, because I do not understand what to do

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is write down the definition of "helix."

Comment: @user66345 I got it! $\alpha$ is a helix iff $k/\tau$ is constant, then is sufficient to prove that $k/\tau = b/a$

Comment: So do you know how to calculate $k$ and $\tau$?

Comment: @user66345 $k(s)=|| \alpha''(s) ||$ and $\tau$...still not looking

Comment: It should be in your textbook, but it's also here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Torsion

Comment: @P.M.O., I think the *usual* definition (characterization) of "helix" is that smooth curve with both curvature and torsion constants, not merely their quotient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$\alpha'(s)=\left(\frac{a}{c}\sin\theta(s)\;,\;\frac{a}{c}\cos\theta(s)\;,\;\frac{b}{c}\right)\implies$$

$$||\alpha'(s)||=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{c}$$

$$t(s):=\frac{\alpha'(s)}{||\alpha'(s)||}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\left(a\sin\theta(s)\;,\;a\cos\theta(s)\;,\;b\right)\implies$$

$$t'(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\left(a\cos\theta(s)\;,\;-a\sin\theta(s)\;,\;0\right)\implies$$

$$\kappa:=\frac{||t'||}{||\alpha'||}=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{ac}{a^2+b^2}$$

I'll let the torsion $\,\tau\,$ for you (check the Frenet formulas...)